# when scroll bottom to top header is sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery

When top scroll is top less than limit bottom and bottom to top scroll Header is Sticky.

```
var lastScroll = 0;

$(document).ready(function($) {

$(window).scroll(function(){
setTimeout(function() { 
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll > lastScroll) {

    $("header").removeClass("menu-sticky");

} 
if (scroll == 0) {
$("header").removeClass("menu-sticky");

}
else if (scroll < lastScroll - 5) {


    $("header").addClass("menu-sticky");

}
lastScroll = scroll;
},0);
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/memdumusaib/d52xcLm3/

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: @PatrickHund I think what you mean is: *Please ask a question.*

Comment: when bottom to top scroll header is sticky. and see example

Comment: Easily work on page